# multiple select using the select method on FormBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<td><div id="candys-<%=@type.id.to_s%>"> 
    <%= f.select(:candy_ids, 
             options_for_select(...), 
         {}, 
         {:multiple=>true, :name => "type[#{@type.id.to_s}][candy_ids[]]"}) %>
</div></td>
```

I end up getting an array of nils.

if I don't add a :name to force the name to be an array, I won't get an array of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there but the last set of square brackets goes on the outside, so:

```
<%= f.select(:candy_ids, 
         options_for_select(...), 
     {}, 
     {:multiple=>true, :name => "type[#{@type.id.to_s}][candy_ids][]"}) %>
```

Although I have to say not specifically designating a :name worked for me too. Not sure what the rest of your model/form looks like though.

Comment: hooray! works. Thanks. Yeah I don't know, not adding a name doesn't put the ids in the type array.